# What case of 'I' should be used in a Participle Clause?

Tags: grammar, participles, grammatical-case

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

1. I being not at home, my friend left a message.
2. Me being not at home, my friend left a message.
3. My being not at home, my friend left a message.

I think that the third sentence can be easily ruled out since *My being not at home* would be a gerund, and we need a participle here.

I have seen sentences like *Him being dead, there was no one remaining to challenge her.* and I **think** they are grammatically correct. Following this trend of using the objective case, I believe that the second sentence would be the correct one, but my teacher says that it should be the first one (probably because the second one does have an informal *feel* to it).

So, **which one of them is the correct one**, and why?

Comment: I would say all the three versions use the _nominative absolute._ I also think that your teacher is right— nominative case is to be preferred over the accusative case both in gerundial and participial clauses.

Comment: @user405662 I didn't know anything about _nominative absolutes_. I read a little about them and it indeed seems to me now that sentence #1 is correct; but that would mean that _Him being dead, there was no one to challenge her._ is incorrect, although I am sure I have seen sentences like that written even in books.

Comment: As @BillJ has pointed out in his answer in such cases using the genitive case is incorrect; the other two cases are acceptable (with nominative case preferred over the accusative case.)

Comment: @user405662 Got it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There are other requirements than grammaticality. Using even the two grammatical variants here would mark a person as being ... let's say, odd. 'John being dead, there was no one remaining to challenge her.' works (being in a literary style).

Comment: All the "-ing phrases" purport to be fronting adverbials. However, none are idiomatic at the very least, there is unnatural ellipsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] [*I being not at home*]*, my friend left a message.*
>
> [2] [*Me being not at home*]*, my friend left a message.*
>
> [3] * [*My being not at home*]*, my friend left a message.*

The bracketed expressions are gerund-participial clauses in adjunct function.

In such constructions, genitive subjects are not permitted at all: the choice is between nominative [2] and accusative [1], with [3] being ungrammatical.

Incidentally, it would be more natural to put the negative marker "not" before the verb rather than after it: "I/me not being at home".

Comment: Thanks Bill for your answer! If I understood it correctly, you are implying that both [1] and [2] are grammatically correct and essentially equivalent. Would you say the same if, say, it were _she_ and _her_ instead of _I_ and _me_ respectively?

Comment: _Accusative_ is formal or informal? @BillJ

Comment: @Arjun Yes: any nominative or accusative case personal pronoun is OK. Note, though, that the accusative is markedly informal and somewhat unlikely: the construction is relatively formal, so the accusative tends to sound out of place here.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically both 1 and 2 are correct. The difference is not a matter of grammar but of style. It's just that 1 is more formal while 2 is less formal.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you cite some sources so that I can read more about this. Also, @user405662 's comment on my question suggests that only nominative case would be grammatically appropriate here. What would you say about that?